# Caffélatex Tubeless Rim Strips w/ Stan's Tire Sealant

Tags: compatibility, tubeless, sealant, rim-tape

The manufacturer (Effetto Mariposa) is telling me that if I run their Caffelatex tubeless rim strips with the regular white Stan's tire sealant, that after 1-2 years the strips will be damaged by the ammonia in the sealant, creating a potential hazard to the rider.

Stan's customer service says their sealant won't damage any of the tubless rim strips that are on the market.

Is there anyone here who's actually tried those Caffélatex strips with Stan's sealant and can tell me which company is right?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: It looks like less than 20 people will see this post in the first day, so I'm guessing the answer is no, no one who sees this will have tried that specific combination.  Perhaps I should be asking for suggestions on where I could find someone who's tried it instead.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check if present Stan's has ammonia in it. It might be only a thing of the past. To get a definite answer you might get the technical data sheet. Ammonia has to be included because of it's toxicity to water organisms as a pollutant.

Comment: https://www.notubes.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/GIS-004_R3_Stans_Tire_Sealant_SDS_GHS.pdf

According to that data sheet it's solvent is indeed propylene glycol. But please get the data sheet for exactly the product you use. For example, in Europe you ought to get a data sheet compatible with REACH.

Comment: The only ammonia in Stan's is the tiny amount that's added during the manufacture of natural latex (an ingredient).  That's what they told me yesterday and it sounds like there's very little ammonia to begin with.  They also told me it's fine to leave a new bottle of sealant open for 5-10 minutes to let the ammonia gas off (though they seemed to think that's unnecessary).

Effetto Mariposa claims ammonia can't off-gas once it's in the tire because it's trapped, but every time I have to pump up the tires it's because air leaked out right?

Comment: @gschenk Ammonia has to be included in the technical data sheet or the sealant?